# FileUpload Package does not exist

Tags: java, io, libraries, apache-commons-fileupload

I want to import `DiskFileItemFactory` class. But after adding libraries `commons-fileupload.jar`  , `commons-io.jar` (Source zip files) to project i get this error:

```
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.*;
//Error: package org.apache.commons.fileupload does not exists
```

I am importing them in Beans component file.
Server: GlassFish on NetBeans.

Comment: well refresh ur project, and do a clean

Comment: are your jars in **/WEB-INF/lib** folder?

Comment: no they are not in it. There is no `lib` folder inside `WEB-INF`

Comment: is your project a **dynamic web project**?btw i didn't down voted your question.

Comment: @Imran yes it is. I am trying to upload image using this `DiskFileItemFactory`

Answer (score 2):

The mentioned package/classes are not present in the compiletime classpath. Basically, Java has no idea what you're talking about when you say to import this and that. It can't find them in the classpath.

drop the jars in **/WEB-INF/lib** folder of the project and this error should disappear.

You can download the jars from here [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) and [commons-fileupload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/)

you can try these steps:

> 1.Right-click the project name (in the "Projects" window) -> New -> Folder, call it (say) "lib". Now open your file browser, navigate to
>   that folder and drop all the custom libraries that you have.
>
> 2.Right-click the project -> Properties -> Libraries -> Compile (tab) -> Add JAR/Folder and add the jar files.

Comment: I made folder named `lib` and put both zip files in it. Cleaned and build the project, but still getting same error..

Comment: For **dynamic web project** by default a **lib** folder is created inside **WEB-INF** folder, i am worried how come it doesn't created for you.

Comment: I have a `lib` folder in main directory (at same level with web, src and others).

Comment: can you post image of your project structure? so that analysis becomes easy

Comment: Where is Deployment Assembly inside Properties? I am using NetBeans not Eclipse

Comment: Should i make folder lib inside web/WEB-INF folder or not?

Comment: have you added the jars in **lib** folder at same level with web, src and others?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62811/discussion-between-imran-and-m-s).

Answer (score 0):

- If you use jar file you need to add it libraries folder.
- If you use netbeans, then select your project and right click on
  libraries folder. It opens up a popup menu. Select Add JAR/Folder -> 
  Select the path where your file is -> click on open button.

Your error will be disappear

Comment: You need to edit this answer to be step-by-step, not just a wall of text. Add bullet points and quotes etc to make it descriptive. Also, cite any outside sources if you have.